# Content Type invalid with GET and 500 error with POST

Tags: c#, ajax

Super new to programming. Trying to send a file to an API to read and return data. Getting an "Internal Server Error" in the controller.
Here is the Ajax call in the view.

```
var FileDate = new FormData($(#uploadFile)[0]);
//#uploadFile is enctype="multipart/form-data"
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "@Url.Content("~/getRates")",
    async: true,
    data: FileData,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(msg){
      //success message
    }
});
```

The error occurs in the controller. Controller below (partial):

```
public string getRates(string ExceptionFileName){

    var files = Request.Form.Files;

    foreach(var file in files){
       FileName = file.FileName;
       //blah blah ... creates new copy of file
    }
    var content = new
    {
        //some content like database name, user id, and such
    }
    string url;
    HttpResponseMessage response;
    var data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content);
    HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(data);
    httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("applocation/json");
    var myHttpClient = _httpClient.CreateClient();

    url = "https://localhost:####/";
    myHttpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);

    //I get a 500 error in the response
    response = myHttpClient.PostAsync("IT4847?", httpContent).Result;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode){
       string sResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
       return "OK";
    }
```

It seems that the API/localhost is never accessed. I have a breakline on the first line of code in the API but it never makes it there. Here's the Post function to API:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Post(dynamic Obj)
    {

       // Step: 1

     }
```

If I use ajax type="POST", I get a 500 error in the response from Controller. I know 500 errors are harder to determine. Is there an obvious issue with what I have?

Comment: You cannot send content with a GET. You must use a POST (or PUT). If you want you can pass information on the query string with a get but that doesn't scale well if you want to pass multiple file names.

Comment: @AndrewHarris Thank you! I will update edit my question for POST only

Comment: If you are getting a 500 error then in your controller you should see an error occurring. Check the console for any errors. Also, is your code literally url = "https://localhost:####/"; or are the #'s an actual port number that matches your API?

Comment: @AndrewHarris #'s are the actual port numbers to the API

Comment: have you checked the console of your controller to see what/if any errors are being thrown?